# Library mismatch OpenSUSE 12.3 - totally borked, update gone bad

Tags: opensuse, zypper

My workstation at work is OpenSUSE 12.3 KDE. I added the pacman repository to update SVN from 1.7.11 to 1.8.?. Later, I ran zypper update which updates all libraries to the latest "stable" build. Well I think it pulled a lot of packages from the pacman repository because it updated around 1800 libraries. Plus, now when I boot it up it says, "Welcome to OpenSUSE 13.1 (Beta 1)" and it doesn't recognize my network card, the video display a wonky, and eclipse won't start. I get a "pointer xyz not found".

Is there a way to reset the libraries without reinstalling? I'm not running brtfs so I have no snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by downloading the full installation media, the 4.7GB disk. Then I ran the "upgrade" program. Even though I was already running 12.3, it removed all my repositories and treated it like I was upgrading from an older version.